# Set the border color of Array of textfield

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

I have around 30 `UITextField` (IBOutlet) in my view controller which I created in the interface builder.

Now I want to set the border color and border width of all these `UITextField`.

So following is the code what I am trying and it is not happening.

```
for (UIView *subView in self.view.subviews) {
        if ([subView isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {

            [[subView layer] setBorderColor:[[UIColor colorWithRed:171.0/255.0 green:171.0/255.0 blue:171.0/255.0 alpha:1.0] CGColor]];
            subView.layer.borderWidth= 1.0f;

        }
 }
```

But if I do it with each object individually, changes are reflecting.

```
       [[textfieldOne layer] setBorderColor:[[UIColor colorWithRed:171.0/255.0 green:171.0/255.0 blue:171.0/255.0 alpha:1.0] CGColor]];
       textfieldOne.layer.borderWidth= 1.0f;
```

Where am I doing the mistake?

Comment: ABove code is working . I have check your code....

Comment: You are correct ,Ooops my mistake , self.view.subviews is the main culprit here which is different in my case. Thanks for the response everyone.

Comment: Could you not use the `appearance` attribute? Like `[[UITextField appearance] setBorderColor:[[UIColor redColor] CGColor]];`

Comment: I tried using appearance before this and it didn't work =\

Answer (score 2):

Your code should work but it is prettier if you typecast your `UIView` (not that I see how it would make much of a difference). Try this

```
for (UIView *subView in self.view.subviews) {
        if ([subView isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
            UITextField *aTextField = (UITextField *)subView;
            [[aTextField layer] setBorderColor:[[UIColor colorWithRed:171.0/255.0 green:171.0/255.0 blue:171.0/255.0 alpha:1.0] CGColor]];
            aTextField.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;

        }
 }
```

Also on a side note; Try not to mix dot notation with brackets as it makes the code quite inconsistent. Choose one and stick it it.

Dot notation

```
aTextField.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor colorWithRed:171.0/255.0 green:171.0/255.0 blue:171.0/255.0 alpha:1.0] CGColor];
aTextField.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
```

Brackets

```
[[aTextField layer] setBorderColor:[[UIColor colorWithRed:171.0/255.0 green:171.0/255.0 blue:171.0/255.0 alpha:1.0] CGColor]];
[[aTextField layer] setBorderWidth:1.0f];
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for (UITextField *subView in self.view.subviews) {
        if ([subView isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {

            [[subView layer] setBorderColor:[[UIColor colorWithRed:171.0/255.0 green:171.0/255.0 blue:171.0/255.0 alpha:1.0] CGColor]];
            subView.layer.borderWidth= 1.0f;

        }
 }
```

Try with this.May this helps you.